# java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: lastScrollData=null

Tags: eclipse, nullpointerexception, appium

I am using Eclipse to compile my code, android studio 4.1.2 for the emulator and Appium Server.

My code:

```java
DesiredCapabilities c=new DesiredCapabilities();
     
c.setCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5554");
c.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
c.setCapability("noReset", "True");
c.setCapability("appPackage", "com.ionicframework.rocassetassuranceapp290415");
c.setCapability("appActivity", "com.ionicframework.rocassetassuranceapp290415.CordovaApp");
    
AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),c);

Thread.sleep(5000);
MobileElement el1 = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByXPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[1]/android.widget.EditText");
el1.click();
```

and I am getting the below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: lastScrollData=null
    at com.google.common.collect.CollectPreconditions.checkEntryNotNull(CollectPreconditions.java:33)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.entryOf(ImmutableMap.java:135)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder.put(ImmutableMap.java:206)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder.put(ImmutableMap.java:220)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder.putAll(ImmutableMap.java:232)
    at io.appium.java_client.HasSessionDetails.getSessionDetails(HasSessionDetails.java:38)
    at io.appium.java_client.HasSessionDetails.getSessionDetail(HasSessionDetails.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.HasSessionDetails.getPlatformName(HasSessionDetails.java:46)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:99)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:111)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:72)
    at MobileApp.Test.main(Test.java:45)
```

Comment: Which of the lines in the code snippet you provided is line 45? It would help a lot if you indicate which one is the failing line. I am assuming it is where you create the driver instance. Have you tried without  `<AndroidElement>`?

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem when use appium v1.21.0 https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases and  io.appium.java-client 5.0.0-BETA9 .

The version of io.appium.java-client is too old,  use io.appium.java-client 6.0.0 solved this problem https://github.com/appium/java-client/releases

And org.seleniumhq.selenium.selenium-remote-driver use version 3.141.59  https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/releases/tag/selenium-3.141.59

Comment: I thought all of them would be solved with the latest version, but I didn't try it.